# How do I program frames?

Tags: roblox

Like if i click on a fridge door and it opens, or click on a chest and the top slides off.

Answer (score 2):

Add a ClickDetector inside of it, and add a script that does what you want to do. To open it sideways you can do this:(It might not turn the right way)

```
for i = 1, 90 do
script.Parent.CFrame = script.Parent.CFrame * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(0, math.pi*90/1, 0)
wait()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a clickdetector, and script it so onclick the parent part moves from one place to another.